# numpy.linalg.lstsqr Errors

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices, model_con and observed_con. model_con is 15x1096, and filled with float values ranging from 0 to about 5. observed_con is size 1096 with float values within approximately the same range. When I run this code:

```
for j in range(1000):
    N = []
    for i in range(800):
        N.append(randint(0,1095)) 
    Cs = model_con[:,N]
    Os = observed_con[N]
    k = np.linalg.lstsq(Cs,Os)[0]
```

I recieve the error:

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Incompatible dimensions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've written it, Cs has shape (15,800) and Os has shape (800,). But lstsq requires Os to be shape (15,) since you're trying to find the least squares solution to Cs x = Os (minimizing ||Cs x - Os||^2 over x). If you change 800 to 15 you'll see that you won't get any errors, but I don't know what you're trying to solve exactly.

In the documentation a, in this instance Cs, has shape (M,N) and b, or Os, has shape (M,).

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Answer (score 0):

False alarm, I found an error in my creation of the matrices. Sorry everybody!